# Random "location not for current program" error

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, uniform

I have an issue with WebGL.

Sometimes, when I add a new shader to my application, I start to get `uniform4f: location not for current program` error (displayed in Chrome console) every frame when I set an uniform of my image drawing shader in my 2D drawing functions.

While I got the same error a few times before, it was not very hard to fix them by doing something random unknown manipulations. However, when I added a screen warping shader, I tried everything I could, even `glFinish` (I think the error occurs because of desynchronization), but nothing helped.

The error occurs when I try to set a vec4 uniform of my 2D image [shader](http://pastebin.com/sSzx1TGT) in the console drawing function. If I swap the console drawing function and the menu drawing function, the menu is not drawn.

Here's the source code of my program creation and switching functions: http://pastebin.com/zDEWWgKV

The error stops if I do anything from the following list:

- Close the menu.
- Load a map and do some 3D rendering (causing switching of programs at least 4 times).
- Enable screen warping (causing switching of programs 1 time).

Could anybody tell me, what may cause the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think it means that you are setting a uniform on a program that's not the current program (i.e. last one passed to `useProgram()`). You could add some checks for that to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the location you are using came from another program. Programs do not share locations, even if they are using the same shaders. Example:

```
// make a vertex and a fragment shader
var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vs, vSource);
gl.compileShader(vs);

var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fs, fSource);
gl.compileShader(fs);

// now make 2 identical programs from those shaders
var p1 = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(p1, vs);
gl.attachShader(p1, fs);
gl.linkProgram(p1);

var p2 = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(p2, vs);
gl.attachShader(p2, fs);
gl.linkProgram(p2);

// Get a uniform location from program1
var location1 = gl.getUniformLocation(p1, "someUniform");

// Try to use that location on program2
gl.useProgram(p2);
gl.uniform4fv(location1, [1, 2, 3, 4]);  // ERROR!!!
```

Trying to use a location from program 1 on program 2 is not allowed. You must get locations for program 2 to set uniforms on program 2.

Comment: I know that you can't set location of another program. The cause of the error is different, I already fixed it. But anyway, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function that sets projection matrices and runs every frame in my code. It iterates on all shaders and `useProgram`s them, but doesn't change `GL.currentprogram`, so if the last shader in the previous frame was `Pic`, and the first shader in the current frame is `Pic` too, but the loop has stopped on, for instance, `Warp`, my shader-selecting function would think that the current shader is `Pic`, while it's not, and won't change the shader.

I fixed it by setting `GL.currentprogram` to `null` and disabling current attribute arrays before iterating on all shaders.